# SCDF REST API. List of Task Schedules is empty

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

According to [SCDF documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#api-guide-resources-task-schedule-list), the `/tasks/schedules` endpoint should return a list of Task Schedules. However, the returned list is empty despite the present schedules, which are visible UI  `https://xxx.yyy.zzz/dashboard/#/tasks-jobs/schedules`.

```
{"_links":{"self":{"href":"https://xxx.yyy.zzz/tasks/schedules?page=0&size=20"}},"page":{"size":20,"totalElements":0,"totalPages":0,"number":0}}
```

At the same time, the `tasks/definitions` endpoint works just fine.

I realise that the tasks are defined in the server database, which the schedules are managed by the skipper. Possibly, it stores info only in CronJobs in Kubernetes.

Is there a setting that "enables" retrieval of data from the skipper?

The version we use is `2.9.3`

Comment: Have you checked the browser development tools network logs to see the request made and response received when visiting the same page?

Comment: Thank you very much! Adding the `platform` parameter is a solution

```tasks/schedules?platform=reference-apps```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SCDF documentation about Task Schedules REST API is not complete. Not only the ["Creating a New Task Schedule"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#api-guide-resources-task-schedule-creating) but all calls take the `platform` parameter.